# Different font size for a mobile device using GWT with CssResource and @if

Tags: css, gwt

In GWT using CssResource and ClientBundle it's possible to have conditional statements such as the following:

```
@if <deferred-binding-property> <space-separated list of values> {
  ... css rules ...
}
```

In my project I would like to have a different font size for mobile devices. I thought I would be able to achieve this using the following code:

```
@def fontSize 1.1875em;
@if formfactor mobile {
  @def fontSize 2.375em;
}
.my_font{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: fontSize;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. It always uses the font size defined in the @if statement regardless of what "formfactor" (a gwt property dependent on the device used) is.
Is there anyone who could explain this, or maybe suggest a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the def in if / else?

```
@if formfactor mobile {
  @def fontSize 2.375em;
} @else{
  @def fontSize 1.1875em;
}

.my_font{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: fontSize;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is [Issue 4697](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4697) in GWT. When variables are substituted in CSS, it seems that none of the conditional processing is applied. However, if you were to add a `fontSize()` function to your `CssResource`-extending interface, then conditional processing *is* applied (that is, for the 'mobile' formFactor permutation, the result of the function would be 2.375 even though '1.1875em' will be substituted in the CSS).

One work-around is to define a 'mobile' formFactor-specific variable and use conditional processing to override the CSS properties where the fontSize variable is used:

```
@def fontSizeMobile 2.375em;
@if formfactor mobile {
    @def fontSize fontSizeMobile;
} @else {
    @def fontSize 1.1875em;
}
.my_font{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: fontSize;
    cursor: default;
}
@if formfactor mobile {
    .my_font{
        font-size: fontSizeMobile;
    }
}
```